# Can I deactivate a Sonar Qube rule just for test classes?

Tags: sonarqube, static-analysis

I want to apply different SonarQube rules for production and test code.

For example: [squid : S1192](https://neptuno.uca.es/sonar/rules/show/squid:S1192?modal=true&layout=false): "*String literals should not be duplicated*". It is quite reasonable in production but for test code is very annoying and can make it less readable.

I see [how to deactive the rule](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24734/how-to-deactivate-a-rule-in-sonarqube) but I can only disable it globally. At the same time I do not want to avoid analysing the whole test set.

Comment: https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/ says "exclude files/directories from Issues detection (specific rules or all of them) but analyze all other aspects" and gives details. does that not work ?

Comment: @MichaelDurrant: Please post as an answer. You deserve the reputation bonus

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this in *Administration* -> *Configuration* -> *Analysis Scope* -> *Restrict Scope of Coding Rules*. You need to specify the code of the rule (without spaces) and a file path pattern to filter. If you use the maven standard `**/src/main/**` will work for you.

[image]

For more information see the [docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/narrowing-the-focus/) where it states that you can:

> ...exclude files/directories from Issues detection (specific rules or
>   all of them) but analyze all other aspects" and gives details.

Answer (score 0):

You can only suppress warnings at the project level, as you said, and at the file/method level. For file/method, it will depend on your language. In Java, you would add an annotation such as:

```
@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("squid:S1192")
```